# Dataframe-renaming multiply columns with othe same name

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with several columns with almost the same name and a number in the end (Hora1, Hora2, ..., Hora12).

I would like to change all column names to GAx, where x is a different number (GA01.0, GA01.1, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we can achieve the above output in many ways. One of the ways I will share here.

```
df.columns = [col.replace('Hora', 'GA01.') for col in df.columns]
```

Please check the screenshot for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the columns by passing a list of column names:

```
columns = ['GA1.0','GA01.1']
df.columns = columns
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import re
df.columns = [re.sub('Hora', 'GA01.', x) for x in df.columns]
```